# 'erase' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20

I'm trying to run the following code in my VS 2019 to test the C++20 feature `std::erase`:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3 };
  std::erase( vec, 2 );
  return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> error C2039:  'erase': is not a member of 'std'

I set the C++ Language Standard to "Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)" in the project settings and the other C++20 feature `contains` works fine.

I tried to run the code in [onlinegdb.com](https://onlinegdb.com/SulBySbiU) and it works fine.

So, the issue is only with `std::erase` and only in VS.

Google didn't help, so I decided to ask here. Has somebody encountered with this issue?

Should be some small thing I overlooked.

Comment: VS2019 encompasses many versions with varying levels of feature support. Does your version claim to support this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170

Comment: It works from MSVC v19.25 and forward.

Comment: Thanks, @chris! I have 16.2.0 version, and it's supported from 16.5.